# Extracting contents from specific meta tags that are not closed using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse out content from specific meta tags. Here's the structure of the meta tags. The first two are closed with a backslash, but the rest don't have any closing tags. As soon as I get the 3rd meta tag, the entire contents between the `<head>` tags are returned. I've also tried `soup.findAll(text=re.compile('keyword'))` but that does not return anything since keyword is an attribute of the meta tag.

```
<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token"/>
<meta name="csrf-token" content="OrpXIt/y9zdAFHWzJXY2EccDi1zNSucxcCOu8+6Mc9c="/>
<meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'>
<meta content='en_US' http-equiv='Content-Language'>
<meta content='c2y_K2CiLmGeet7GUQc9e3RVGp_gCOxUC4IdJg_RBVo' name='google-site-    verification'>
<meta content='initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,width=device-width' name='viewport'>
<meta content='notranslate' name='google'>
<meta content="Learn about Uber's product, founders, investors and team. Everyone's Private Driver - Request a car from any mobile phone—text message, iPhone and Android apps. Within minutes, a professional driver in a sleek black car will arrive curbside. Automatically charged to your credit card on file, tip included." name='description'>
```

Here's the code:

```
import csv
import re
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

req3 = Request("https://angel.co/uber", headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0')
page3 = urlopen(req3).read()
soup3 = BeautifulSoup(page3)

## This returns the entire web page since the META tags are not closed
desc = soup3.findAll(attrs={"name":"description"})
```

Comment: So what output are you hoping to get?

Comment: I want the content of the meta tag that has name="description"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Edited:
Added regex for case sensitivity as suggested by @Albert Chen.

Python 3 Edit:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib.request

page3 = urllib.request.urlopen("https://angel.co/uber").read()
soup3 = BeautifulSoup(page3)

desc = soup3.findAll(attrs={"name": re.compile(r"description", re.I)}) 
print(desc[0]['content'])
```

Although I'm not sure it will work for every page:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib

page3 = urllib.urlopen("https://angel.co/uber").read()
soup3 = BeautifulSoup(page3)

desc = soup3.findAll(attrs={"name": re.compile(r"description", re.I)}) 
print(desc[0]['content'].encode('utf-8'))
```

Yields:

```
Learn about Uber's product, founders, investors and team. Everyone's Private Dri
ver - Request a car from any mobile phoneΓÇötext message, iPhone and Android app
s. Within minutes, a professional driver in a sleek black car will arrive curbsi
de. Automatically charged to your credit card on file, tip included.
```

Comment: I tried this - I get a syntax error on `desc` for the statement print desc[0]['content'].encode('utf-8') ... if I figure out why I'll post back here.. This was due to the print statement not being enclosed in () - so, print (desc[0]['content'].encode('utf-8'))... I am using python 3.4.1, not updating answer because not sure if version-specific

Comment: Yes sorry, this was for python2.7

Answer (score 4):

Description is Case-Sensitive.So, we need to look for both 'Description' and 'description'.

Case1: 'Description' in [Flipkart.com](http://view-source:http://www.flipkart.com/)

Case2: 'description' in [Snapdeal.com](http://view-source:http://www.snapdeal.com/)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url= 'https://www.flipkart.com'
page3= requests.get(url)
soup3= BeautifulSoup(page3.text)
desc= soup3.find(attrs={'name':'Description'})
if desc == None:
    desc= soup3.find(attrs={'name':'description'})
try:
    print desc['content']
except Exception as e:
    print '%s (%s)' % (e.message, type(e))
```

Comment: If both exist, probably want to combine the two results instead of only searching for lowercase, if uppercase is None.

Answer (score 4):

```
soup3 = BeautifulSoup(page3, 'html5lib')
```

xhtml requires the meta tag to be closed properly, html5 does not. The html5lib parser is more "permissive".

Answer (score 4):

Try (based on [this](http://blog.davidziegler.net/post/122176962/a-python-script-to-automatically-extract-excerpts) blog post)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
...
desc = ""
for meta in soup.findAll("meta"):
    metaname = meta.get('name', '').lower()
    metaprop = meta.get('property', '').lower()
    if 'description' == metaname or metaprop.find("description")>0:
        desc = meta['content'].strip()
```

Tested against the following variants:

- `<meta name="description" content="blah blah" />` ([Example](http://www.ouc.com/))
- `<meta id="MetaDescription" name="DESCRIPTION" content="blah blah" />` ([Example](http://www.firstorlando.com/))
- `<meta property="og:description" content="blah blah" />` ([Example](http://zevross.com/blog/2014/05/16/using-the-python-library-beautifulsoup-to-extract-data-from-a-webpage-applied-to-world-cup-rankings/))

Used BeautifulSoup version **4.4.1**

Answer (score 1):

I think here use regexp should be better:
example:

```
resp = requests.get('url')
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text)
desc = soup.find_all(attrs={"name": re.compile(r'Description', re.I)})
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by ingo you could use a less strict parser like html5.

```
soup3 = BeautifulSoup(page3, 'html5lib')
```

but be sure to have `python-html5lib` parser available on the system.