# BeautifulSoup not picking up meta tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, meta

I have a simple script that gets an html page and tries to output the contents of the meta tag for keywords. Somehow, it is not picking up the content of the keywords meta tag even through the html contains the tag. Any help is appreciated.

```
    url = “https://www.mediapost.com/publications/article/316086/google-facebook-others-pitch-in-app-ads-brand-s.html”
    req = urllib2.Request(url=url)
    f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    mycontent = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(mycontent, 'html.parser')
    keywords = soup.find("meta", property="keywords")
    print keywords
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check it properly the meta tag you are looking for has attribute **name** not **property** so change your code to

```
keywords = soup.find("meta", attrs={'name':'keywords'})
```

and then to display the content you need to write

```
print keywords['content']
```

Output:

> Many more major brands are pumping big ad dollars into mobile games,
>   pushing Google, Facebook and others into the in-app gaming ad space.
>   Some believe this is in response to brands searching for a secure,
>   safe place to run video ads and engage with consumers. 03/16/2018

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
keywords = soup.select_one('meta[name="keywords"]')['content']
```

```
>>> keywords
'Many more major brands are pumping big ad dollars into mobile games, pushing Google, Facebook and others into the in-app gaming ad space. Some believe this is in response to brands searching for a secure, safe place to run video ads and engage with consumers. 03/16/2018'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `'lxml'` instead of `'html.parser'` and use `soup.find_all`

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, 'lxml')
keywords = soup.find_all('meta',attrs={"name": 'keywords'})
for x in keywords:
    print(x['content'])
```

#### Output

```
Many more major brands are pumping big ad dollars into mobile games, pushing Google, Facebook and others into the in-app gaming ad space. Some believe this is in response to brands searching for a secure, safe place to run video ads and engage with consumers. 03/16/2018
```

Comment: But I only want to extract the content of one meta tag, where meta name="keywords"?

Comment: updated,[thanks to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134318/extracting-contents-from-specific-meta-tags-that-are-not-closed-using-beautifuls#18135015)