# How to get the content from meta tag(Python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
<meta data-react-helmet="true" name="branch:deeplink:productId" content="c5e9bc51-86ec-5d1e-8ed1-b28572a49985">
```

My code:

```
id=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/head/meta[16]')
print(id.get_attribute('content'))
```

This is  my result:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/user/Desktop/play.py
GET

Process finished with exit code 0
```

How can I get the content value

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134318/extracting-contents-from-specific-meta-tags-that-are-not-closed-using-beautifuls/18135015

Comment: why can't you use `driver.find_element_by_tag_name('meta')` and then use the get_attribute() function?

Comment: You will need to provide more information. For example the website you are trying to call, as well as more code, as we don't know, what your code is doing. This is currently not reproducable